# Monitoring home network activity

Tags: network-monitoring

I have a somewhat complex home network and I want to be able to monitor network activity both inbound/outbound. My network consists of 5 VLANs to segregate unmanaged network, user devices network, guest network, home automation network, and management network.

I have a ESXi server with 2.4GHz 8-c Atom CPU and 32GB memory. I have 2-c and 8GB remaining that I can dedicate. My 48 port switch is also managed.

I searched online and read various tools like Snort, Untangled, Sophos Home UTM, etc but I'm not sure if I need several of them, or just one, and how it will provide monitoring of my network to know if any suspicious activity is found.

Some extra features, but not necessary, would be to check mail (spam) and openVPN integration. I'd also like a daily report if possible to know how much inbound/outbound bandwidth was consumed. It can be emailed or viewed online.

I don't mind paying for a service, I can probably afford $100-$250 a year for annual subscription. It just has to handle multiple VLANs, and something like 80+ IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you regarding monitoring for suspicious ativity, but for monitoring of the health of the network there are various tools.

PRTG is a Network monitoring tool which is free up to 100 sensors.
I don't know if they mean 100 host or if one host can consist of multiple sensors.
I don't really have any experience using it, but I know it is widely used for monitoring network health and bandwidth usage.

MRTG can also be used if only bandwidth usage is of interest.

HP NNM is another tool for monitoring.
It's very powerful and has alot of plugins (SPi). It can be used with HP NPS for statistics.
I know the have a free version for trail which should be limited to a number of hosts. 
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/network-node-manager-i-network-management-software/